# SI align on units

Tags: alignment

I write latex as follows: `\SI{206540}{\metre\per\second}`

This gets written as `206.54 km/s`

In a table cell, this is right-aligned after the s.

How can I get it aligned after the 6? or after the 4?

or do I need to cut the units off and put them in another column?

Comment: Hi, please, can you add a full minimal working example to abbreviate the time and to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Aligned in table depends on type of column. At `c` columns it is centered.

Comment: A minimal working example would be really useful here. What kind of contents do the other cells contain?